# Error 401 Unauthorized. How to Use the same token for different Urls?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.Net Identity using Oauth2 a token is created once the user is authenticated posting User and Password.

Before making a call to an action from one API, the user must ask for a token:

```
http://mysite/auth/token
```

Once the token is received, all Web Api calls can be done, sending the

`Authorization: Bearer <token>` header:

```
GET http://mysite/auth/product/1
PUT http://mysite/auth/client/42
```

I have several Web Apis that use a centralised Security System for Authentication,
the problem is that I receive Unauthorizaed (401) when I try to call different Api (with different URL). For example:

```
GET http://mysite/myapi/product/1
```

If the Security is centralised and both APIs are using the same Users Database for Authentication, how can I use the same token for different Urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution adding the same *machineKey* tag in both Web.config files:

```
<system.web>
...
<machineKey validationKey="57B449BBA8F9E656087FF7848727E122C5F5966F65AC0FC25FB3532193B59CFCD13B370883FFC184C1F1500638F33E6F67B37CAED1D9BC65BBC6CFFB232BFD0B" decryptionKey="6D9FBE88D16B3FA5B5E6B37460BBE50DA85D5B4C482159006B5A337C58AA9E79" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
...
</system.web>
```

as is suggested on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623313/owin-multi-app-bearer-token-authentication) using a machineKey generator.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx):

> **Sharing Authentication Tickets Across Applications**
>   If you need a single logon to work across multiple applications located in separate
>   virtual directories, you need to share a common authentication ticket.
>   To configure a common authentication ticket, you must manually
>   generate validationKey and decryptionKey values and ensure that each
>   application shares these values. If you want to share tickets across
>   all applications on your server you can set these manual values on the
>    element in the machine level Web.config file. To share
>   tickets across specific applications, you can use a 
>   element with common validationKey and decryptionKey values in the
>   relevant application's Web.config files.

**Updated - Security Warning**

> Security warning
>
> There are many web sites that will generate a  element for
>   you with the click of a button. Never use a  element that
>   you obtained from one of these sites. It is impossible to know whether
>   these keys were created securely or if they are being recorded to a
>   secret database. You should only ever use  configuration
>   elements that you created yourself.

Read the Appendix A on the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218#AppendixA) to know how to generate your own machineKey element.