# Owin authentication between MVC 5 and Web API (separate IIS applications)

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, bearer-token

I have a working app with MVC5 and Web API (both different IIS applications) using Forms Authentication and Bearer token. Yes, they must remain two separate IIS applications.  I am using the auth token as the username in my Forms Authentication cookie and that's how I am able to pass the token back and forth from MVC and Web API.

I am also using Asp.net Identity 2.0.

I would like to take Forms Authentication out of the equation and just use Owin Authentication but the User.Identity.IsAuthenticate is always false in my MVC app when I do have a Bearer Token issued.

Can anyone point me to code showing how I can remember auth token between MVC and Web API w/o Forms Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your machineyKey on web..config should be the unified, do not generate machineKey using any online tool, please generate them using power-shell. You can find more about this by reading my [blog post here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/).

Answer (score 0):

All machineKey of your webconfig files must be the same for domains that will share athentication.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361240/asp-net-identity-use-the-same-token-for-different-urls/25362389#25362389) about how to set it.