# OWIN bearer authentication failing in web api 2

Tags: c#-4.0, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am trying to implement web api 2 based Claim based authentication with oauth tokens. For this i have created

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(PMW.Api.Startup))]
    public class Startup
    {
        //private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        //private IUserService _userService;
        //private ICommonService _commonService;

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            IUnityContainer container = GetUnityContainer();
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependancyResolver(container);

            //_unitOfWork = container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
            //_userService = container.Resolve<IUserService>();
            //_commonService = container.Resolve<ICommonService>();

            MapAutomapper();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            //var OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            //{
            //    Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider(),
            //    AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
            //    {
            //        OnCreate = create,
            //        OnReceive = receive
            //    },
            //};

            //app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

        }

        public static Action<AuthenticationTokenCreateContext> create = new Action<AuthenticationTokenCreateContext>(c =>
        {
            c.SetToken(c.SerializeTicket());
        });

        public static Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext> receive = new Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext>(c =>
        {
            c.DeserializeTicket(c.Token);
            c.OwinContext.Environment["Properties"] = c.Ticket.Properties;
        });

        private void MapAutomapper()
        {
            //Mapper code
        }


        private IUnityContainer GetUnityContainer()
        {
            //Create UnityContainer          
            IUnityContainer container = //unity mapping 

            return container;
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }


    }
```

and authorization class is defined as below

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            IUnityContainer container = //unity code for mapping login related service



            var _commonService=container.Resolve<ICommonService>() ;
            var password =// Encrypt password



            UserService _userService = new UserService(container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>(),
                container.Resolve<IUserMasterRepository>(), container.Resolve<IUserDetailRepository>());
            var userToPass = new UserDTO()
            {
                EmailId = context.UserName,
                Password = password 
            };

            var user = _userService.AuthenticateUser(userToPass);


            if (!user.Succeeded)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);



        }
    }
```

The code is working properly and generating tokens to client side application. However, if i use Authrize attribute as shown below . It always fails with error 401 unauthorized.

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public UserDTO Test()
        {
            return new UserDTO();
        }
```

Here is the snapshot of request and failing method details.
[image]

Please let us know what i am missing in order to implement flow of authorization properly.

Comment: Can you show how are you doing the GET from Test method? I mean, are sending: Authorization: Bearer <token> as a Request Header correctly?

Comment: I have added snapshot containing reference to request part with authorization bearer token.

Comment: From the info in the snapshot, it seems you have 2 projects: One for authorization and another one for resources. Have you checked that machinekey in both webconfig files are identical? Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901414/owin-authentication-between-mvc-5-and-web-api-separate-iis-applications/25942811#25942811

Comment: I have added machine key also to web.config of both of this project. But still no luck Authorize attribute fails everytime after setting claim as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Check my working sample in this article about using Web api 2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a CORS problem; try adding these lines in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

    if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] {allowedOrigin});

    ...
}
```