# How can I validate a received token in Asp.NET WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin, bearer-token, authorize-attribute

My project contains an ASP.NET MVC application (with no authentication) and two Web APIs.

The first API (Account API) is built on top of Owin middleware, using ASP.NET identity, in order to have a token-based authentication for ASP.NET MVC.

This works very fine for ASP.NET MVC.

But the second API is a data handler API (Data API).

The problem is that I need to authorize the incoming requests on Data API. From the ASP.NET MVC application, I have the following request.

**Start Edit 1**

```
// The MVC controller makes a request in order to authenticate the user.
// If the authentication succeeds, an access token is returned.

var authorizationUrl = "my.authorization.api";
HttpResponseMessage result = httpClient.PostAsync(authorizationUrl, content).Result;


// In the Home controller I have these lines of code.

var user = ((ClaimsPrincipal) HttpContext.Current.User);
var token = x.Claims.First(t => t.Type == "AccessToken").Value;


// Now I just need to call the Data API.

var dataUrl = "my.data.api/home";
var request = WebRequest.Create(dataUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

The data API has an [Authorize] attribute on HomeController and I receive 401 Unauthorized every time I call any method.

**End Edit 1**

The questions is: how can I validate the incoming request (on Data API) using the accessToken from request's header (sent from MVC application)?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to implement single sign-on (SSO) between two APIs?

Comment: Well, since only the MVC application is calling the other API, yes.
Edit 1: If I have other multiple APIs that do not interact each other, I think there should be the same way of how the request should treated.

Comment: Do you want to extract the Bearer token sent from your ASP.NET MVC in your Data API? Are you getting an unauthorized message from your API?

Comment: @Damith, yes, I receive an unauthorized message from my API. I do not know how to use the Bearer token in order to authorize the request that came with it.

Comment: @PianoSong Will you able to share your code with us? At least sample.

Comment: @PianoSong How you passing the token currently are you setting the token in authroize header?

Comment: @Damith, I have updated my question and added more example code.

Comment: Maybe this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361240/error-401-unauthorized-how-to-use-the-same-token-for-different-urls